# How to get Value by VBA from Source code not using Tag or ID of the element

Tags: html, excel, vba

I'm trying to use VBA for web scraping (https://www.booking.com/hotel/in/dream-catcher-home-stay.en-gb.html) and get numerical value for "b_hotel_id" line in the code below

```
<td class="line-number" value="568"></td>
<td class="line-content">b_hotel_id: '554615',</td>
```

but I don't know how to refer to it, as there is no ID or TAG.
This data is hidden from website and visible only in the source code.

I was trying to fetch the data using this VBA code:

```
Public Sub GetValueFromBrowser()
    Dim ie As Object
    Dim url As String
    Dim bkid As String

    url = "https://www.booking.com/hotel/in/dream-catcher-home-stay.en-gb.html"
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With ie
      .Visible = 0
      .navigate url
       While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
         DoEvents
       Wend
    End With

    Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
    Set Doc = ie.document

    bkid = Trim(Doc.getElementsByName("b_hotel_id:")(0).Value)
    Range("A1").Value = myPoints

End Sub
```

Could you please help?

Comment: What has this to do with JavaScript and node.js?

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613) • And you should show your VBA code you have tried.

Comment: I've added the last code I was using.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I could not find the HTML code

```
<td class="line-number" value="568"></td>
<td class="line-content">b_hotel_id: '554615',</td>
```

in that URL

```
url = "https://www.booking.com/hotel/in/dream-catcher-home-stay.en-gb.html"
```

but you can extract the number like below:

```
Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
Set Doc = ie.document

Const find_string As String = "b_hotel_id: '"
Dim find_in As String
find_in = Doc.head.innerText

Dim id_start As Long
id_start = InStr(1, find_in, find_string) + Len(find_string)

Dim id_end As Long
id_end = InStr(id_start, find_in, "'")

MsgBox Mid$(find_in, id_start, id_end - id_start)
```

Comment: Great! Worked perfectly, thank you! I'm trying to pull coordinates the same way as well, by putting "booking.env.b_map_center_longitude" instead of "b_hotel_id: " and id_start, find_in, ";"  but with no success. I wonder is there anything else I should edit??